# Override lost password form in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

Default forgot password form is an `Email` form field. I have a licence number attached to each user. As a user, I want to get the reset password link by entering my licence number instead of email.

I've found a way around to override the functionality side but not the form. What I've done till now

Filename: *_config.php*

`Object::useCustomClass('MemberLoginForm', 'ExtendLoginForm');`

Filename: *ExtendLoginForm.php*

Just as a test - override `forgotPassword` method

```
class ExtendLoginForm extends MemberLoginForm
{

    public function forgotPassword($data) {
        // Ensure password is given

        $this->sessionMessage('This works', 'bad');

        $this->controller->redirect('Security/lostpassword');
        return;
    }
}
```

Session message is successfully printed with a redirect to the same page.

How can I override the form to make it a `Text` field instead of `Email` field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, just a general tip, you should avoid using Object::useCustomClass() in favour of Injector (https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.0/reference/injector/). Object::useCustomClass() is more of a 2.4 thing.

The forgot password form is generated in `Security`. You can try using a custom implementation of that class as well, and overloading the `ForgotPasswordForm` method.

*config.yml*

```
Injector:
  Security:
    class: MyCustomSecurity
```

*MyCustomSecurity.php*

```
class MyCustomSecurity extends Security
{
    public function LostPasswordForm()
    {
        $form = parent::LostPasswordForm();
        $form->Fields()->replaceField('Email', TextField::create('Email'));

        return $form;
    }
}
```

Comment: It could help to stipulate TextField::create('LicenceNumber') instead of TextField::create('Email'), just for differentiation.

Comment: Naming the field 'Email' is compulsory, unless you want to overload another method. You could change the label, though. TextField::create('Email', 'License number');